# Form selecting from array

Tags: html, ruby, forms

How do I input values from an array instead of typing them into the f.select. The reason I want to change this is because the list of options now changed based on other values.

I have something called an outstanding and I want to put each outstanding into the list of things that can be selected.

```
@outstandings.each go into the f.select
```

or something like that. Thanks.

```
<div class = "well">
   <%= form_for @userupload, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :nealname, "Neal's Name" %>
      <%= f.select :nealname, ['One Time','As Needed', 'Quarterly', 'Yearly'] %>
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like this

You can change the .name to .date or .whateveryouwant

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass this array as a second argument to `f.select`:

```rb
<%= f.select :nealname, @outstandings %>
```

Or if you want to extend some static values with dynamic ones you can do it like this:

```rb
<%= f.select :nealname, ['One Time','As Needed', 'Quarterly', 'Yearly', *@outstandings] %>
```

Note, in the second example you can move `*@outstandings` to the beginning of an array or between of any of the static values.